# Masstransit RabbitMQ publisher fails to publish "correct" contract

Tags: asp.net-core, properties, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-webapi, masstransit

I have been playing around for a while with Masstransit and RabbitMQ creating message contracts to enable communication between two .NET core web API's and I have stumbled across the following.

Suppose I have the contract specified below in both projects:

```
public class Profile : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public DefaultMode Mode { get; set; }

    public string SuperMode { get; set; }

    public ExtraClient? Client { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I publish a message

```
await _publishEndPoint.Publish<Profile>(profileUpdate);
```

The other end (consumer on the receiver/subscriber API) is able to get only primitive type fields, for example, **Name**, **Description** and **IsActive**.

The rest of the fields are parsed as ***null*** even though I am well aware that prior publishing the properties of ***profileUpdate*** have proper values.

Has anyone faced something similar?

Is it because of the inheritance?

Kind regards,

***Edit#1: Syntax***

***Edit#2: Posting more information***

As requested here is my consumer class:

```
public class ProfileUpdateConsumer : IConsumer<Profile>
{
    private readonly IProfilesHub _profileHub;

    public ProfileUpdateConsumer(IProfilesHub profileHub)
    {
        _profileHub = profileHub;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Profile> context)
    {
        await _profileHub.BroadcastProfileUpdate(context.Message);
    }
}
```

And here is my publisher class:

public class ProfilePublisher : IPublisher
    {
        private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndPoint;

```
    public ProfilePublisher(IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
    {
        _publishEndPoint = publishEndpoint;
    }

    public async Task PublishProfileUpdate(object profileUpdate)
    {
        await _publishEndPoint.Publish<Profile>(profileUpdate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you shared all classes that are available to the published, also to the consumer?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev Yes definitely, both consumer and publisher share the same classes, but for clarification it is a shared project and not a shared class library. Do you think this might be affecting it?

Comment: If you could post the class you're publishing, and the consumer class that is failing to get the fields it would help. My guess is you're publishing the base type _Profile_ and therefore the subclasses message types are not available. But again, code talks here.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I have updated with more code, is that sufficient enough?

Comment: Why object? `public async Task PublishProfileUpdate(object profileUpdate)` - this should be PublishProfileUpdate<T>(T update) where T : Profile -- though why not just publish T?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I am using object because Profile is coming from originally another Profile type which lies inside a data access library so it has to be casted to the Profile I am publishing. I am aware that this is not optimal but for now the classes are identical.

Comment: Then you should cast it before calling MassTransit or remove the generic type from the method call. By specifying a type, and passing object, it's going to use a message initializer, which creates a new type to serialize. If you just call `Publish(object something`, it will call object.GetType() and publish as that type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209457/discussion-between-chris-patterson-and-davelis4).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but for anyone who might come across this.

After discussing with @Chris Patterson ,

I did a manual conversion of the one data type to the other, and made sure that all fields are there.

This worked, even though I still feel quite puzzled as to what was causing this behavior.